# Member function return a function

Tags: c++, pointers, return, public, member

```
a* b::find() const
{
  a* pointr = head;

  return pointr;

}
```

This is my code but visual studio is underlining pointr in the return pointr line? What's wrong with my code?

**EDIT: SORRY TYPO**

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do and show more code. Right now it is unclear. If Als answer solved your problem accept his answer.

Comment: It would be much easier if you show us the actual error message VS gives you.

Comment: is there an actual warning message from the IDE?

Comment: Probably one of those stupid spell-check features they put in which is stupid as there is nothing in the C++ standard that say you have to use correctly spelt English words, although meaningful identifiers are always advantageous, of course.

Answer (score 3):

```
a* pointer = head;

return pointr;
```

You d not have any variable declared as `pointr` in the scope of the function, How will the compiler know unless you declare it?

`pointr` and `pointer` are not same, there is an `e` missing.

Assuming that is a typo,
Your function returns a pointer but what it points to is important in this case. If `head` is a local variable or pointer without dynamic memory allocation(pointing to local object) then your pointer `pointer` is pointing to a local object, which will be destroyed once the function returns and will be a dangling pointer.

Remember the Rule:
**You should not return reference or pointer to an variable local to function.**

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong variable returned

> return pointr;

in your code. It is not defined in the scope.